# Convert SQL query into Django ORM

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I have SQL query, I need to use in Django with ORM technique.

```
SELECT a.id, a.amount, SUM(b.amount)
FROM cashflow_statement a, cashflow_statement b
WHERE b.id <= a.id GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.id
```

Edit:
Django Model

```
class Statement(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Input Data

```
id, amount, date
1.    10   25/06/2020
2.    -10   25/06/2020
3.    40   25/06/2020
4.    10   25/06/2020
5.    -30   25/06/2020
6.    10   25/06/2020


Need Output:
id, amount, sum
1.   10.     10 
2.   -10.    0
3.    40.    40
4.   10.     50
5.   -30.    20
6.    10.    30
```

Comment: Please share the relevant models.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Added models and output what I need, Above Sql giving relevant output.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Django does not support aggregates in subqueries, but with a workaround, we can "trick" the system in generating a correct query:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Sum, Subquery, Value

Statement.objects.annotate(
    sum=Subquery(
        Statement.objects.filter(
            pk__lte=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values(x=Value(0)).order_by('x').annotate(
            sum=Sum('amount')
        ).values('sum')[:1]
    )
)
```

Comment: ProgrammingError at /statement/
non-integer constant in ORDER BY
LINE 1: ..."cashflow_statement"."id") GROUP BY NULL ORDER BY NULL ASC  ...

Getting error. If I removed, `values(x=Value(None)).order_by('x')` after this, getting same value of `sum` in each Statement. so it's not updating according to statements

Comment: @NeerajKumar: this is `PostgreSQL`?

Comment: @NeerajKumar: with PostgreSQL, you probably need to pass an int, and removing values will of course yield the same value, since then we GROUP BY the primary key of the `Statement` object.

Comment: Yes, It's Postgresql

Answer (score 0):

```
x=Statement.objects.filter(date='your date')
sum=0
for i in x:
   sum+=x.amount
```

maybe i have mistake in code but i think you are looking for .filter() part. if you need to use multiple filters together it's somethink like this:

```
x=Statement.objects.filter(date='your date').filter(amount<10)
```